# Keyboard shortcut to "Show Applications"

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I want a keyboard shortcut that is equivalent to pressing the dotted "Show Applications" button on the Ubuntu dock. The closest thing in **Settings > Devices > Keyboard** is **Show all applications** (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), but this shows not only all applications, but all activities as well (maybe a bug?). For example, here is a sequence of actions:

1. I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to get up the applications dash.
2. The
   applications dash pops up as expected.
3. Now I want to close the
   applications dash, I hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> OR <kbd>Escape</kbd>.
4. It goes away,
   but now the activities dash is there instead of the desktop or
   whatever I had before Step 1).

Comment: @pomsky Someone installed the OS for me and set up accounts, but this is been happening ever since I logged in for the 1st time. I just noticed something, when I *do* press "Show Applications", I *still* get the activities to show!

Comment: @pomsky I understand that you're trying to help, but I'm reluctant to take screenshots of my dash. I just learned that the Superkey is supposed to open up the dash (list of installed applications), and not the activities. My Superkey opens up the activities (open applications).

Comment: @pomsky Sorry for that. I read on a few blogs that superkey launches the applications, not the activities. Maybe that was for unity.

Comment: @pomsky The pictures are exactly what I'm getting. But here is what I meant: 1) I press <Super>+<A> to get up the applications dash. 2) The applications dash pops up as expected. 3) Now I want to close the applications dash, I hit <Super>+<A> OR <Escape>. 4) It goes away, but now the activities dash is there instead of the desktop or whatever I had before Step 1).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you're describing is a standard behaviour.

- Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> brings up the "*Activities*" overview (same as clicking "Activities" in the top-left). Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> again brings you back to the desktop.
- Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> brings up the applications list (same as clicking "Show Applications" icon in the Ubuntu dock).
  But pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *again* or pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> won't take you back to the desktop, it takes you to the Activities overview instead (standard behaviour from GNOME shell). Press *only* <kbd>Super</kbd> when you have the applications list open to get back to your desktop.

Comment: Thank you. Marking solved because this is standard behavior.

Comment: One of the less intuitive things imo ..

Comment: what is Super??

Comment: @Pavlos It's usually the key with the Windows logo.

Comment: It might be standard, but it is still bad behaviour.

Comment: And well `super` + `d` shows the Desktop

Answer (score 0):

I actually created a lightweight deb installer to do this, check out my repo here https://github.com/milan102/Ubuntu-Launchpad

The installation instructions are in the github README. The program is a simple shell script that invokes the keyboard shortcut for showing applications (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)

It's not a direct keyboard shortcut like you were asking, but it's pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

use [dash to panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) extension. It has the the setting to work with escape

I didn't actually found the setting. But escape started working once I installed it.
It also has {click empty space to close overview} and lot more.
It may help you