# How to disable or remap ALT key overlay

Tags: gui

The (left) alt key brings up an overlay in Ubuntu 20.04.  How do I turn this off, or set it to a different key.  It's interfering with some functionality in Path of Exile.

Nothing in the keyboard shortcuts utility refers to the naked ALT key.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, perhaps the overlay name is 'Show Applications' and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072043/keyboard-shortcut-to-show-applications?rq=1) is some ideas to change it.

Comment: Please clarify: by default, it is the left Super key, not the left Alt key that brings up the overlay. If needed, correct by editing your question.